# install TARGETS given target "Boost::boost" which does not exist

Tags: boost

when I try to build the project with `cmake` this error appears:

`install TARGETS given target "Boost::boost" which does not exist.`

[image]

I tried to specify BOOST_ROOT, BOOST_INCLUDEDIR, BOOST_LIBRARYDIR but nothing to do, could you help me?